# Cannot get my relationship repository method to work

Tags: c#, linq, repository, entity

I have the following repo method:

```
public class EFX_YRelationshipRepository : IX_YRelationshipRepository
{

    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IQueryable<X_YRelationship> Relationships
    {
        get
        {
            return context.X_Ys;
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<X> GetAsByYID(int yID)
    {
        IQueryable<X>xs = 
            from x in context.Xs
            join r in Relationships on c.XID equals r.XID
            join y in context.Ys on r.YID equals y.YID
            where y.YID == yID
            select new X();

        return xs;
    }
    ...
```

I am calling it from my controller:

```
    public ActionResult ListByY(int yID, int page = 1, string sort = "Name", bool desc = false)
    {
        IEnumerable<X> xsByY = xRelationshipRepository.GetXsByYID(yID);

        ListViewModel<X> model = new ListViewModel<X>
        {
            Items = xsByY
                .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = xsByY.Count(),
                Sort = sort,
                Desc = desc
            }
        };
        return View("_List", model);
    }
```

I get the error:

```
The entity or complex type 'Something.Domain.Concrete.X' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
```

for line:

```
Line 79:             ListViewModel<X> model = new ListViewModel<X>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Side notes:**

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Y> Ys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<X> Xs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<X_YRelationship> Xs_Ys { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTEXT:**

The context of this issue is that I have 3 database tables: Xs Ys and X_Ys( that's the relationship table btw)

**I want to have a list of Xs that have been related to a Y**... So I have made 3 dbSets and a relationship repository that contains a function that will do this.

This repository has one dbContext... and the function just needs to return those Xs to my controller so I can push them to my view.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting an empty instance of X instead of a matching entity.
Change the select-row to:`select x;`

Edit:
You should not use joins to traverse relationships, instead use the foreign key properties on your entities (assuming 1-to-1 relationships):

```
IQueryable<X>xs = context.Xs
    .Where(x => x.Relationship.Any(r => r.Any(y => y.YID == yID)))
```

Comment: I'm now getting: 

Invalid object name 'dbo.X_YRelationship'. I've added extra information to original question including the EFDbContext class and the Relationships method of my repository

Comment: To your answer, I have an existing database that I am just plotting out with classes... The database (SQL) does have foreign keys declared but not within the classes themselves. My relationships are also many to many... I really would like to use the joins.

Comment: To explain further, an X or a Y are not necessarily linked to anything and an X may be linked to many Ys.

Comment: Do you want X:s that has one or more links to a matching Y?

Comment: I adde context to my question. Thanks for hanging on in there with me!

Comment: I figured it out but I do not understand why it works now? So the issue was that my public DbSet<X_YRelationship> Xs_Ys { get; set; } used X_YRelationship class whereas it actually had to be called Xs_Ys... I thought that it was the property name that was the link to the table and that you could call the class anything??? im confused?

Comment: I think thats the convention for a many-to-many relation, assuming your relationship table ONLY contains foreign keys.